# Continuous WARN hdfs.DFSClient: zero while reading TFRecords stored in HDFS via the TensorFlow Dataset API

Tags: tensorflow, hadoop, hdfs, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

When I use the TensorFlow dataset API to read TFRecords files stored in HDFS, the following warning information continuously appears in the terminal.

```
WARN hdfs.DFSClient: zero
```

The training and prediction results are both normal.

What is causing this and is there a way to silence this warning information?